# 'OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long' error when i'm using RandomizedSearchCV on XGBOOST

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, data-science, xgboost

This is my code:

```
def create_XGBoost_classifier(X_train, y_train):

import xgboost as xgb


kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
xgb = xgb.XGBClassifier(random_state=42)

learning_rate = get_learning_rate()

xgb_hyperparameters = {
    # 'n_estimators': np.arange(2000, 5001, 1000).tolist(),
    'n_estimators': [100],
    'max_depth':  np.arange(3, 16, 1).tolist() ,
    'learning_rate': learning_rate ,
    'min_child_weight':  np.arange(0, 8.01, 0.1).tolist(),
    'subsample':  np.arange(0.25, 1.01, 0.025).tolist(),
    'colsample_bytree': np.arange(0.3, 1.01, 0.025).tolist(),
    'colsample_bylevel': np.arange(0.3, 1.01, 0.025).tolist(),
    'min_child_weight':  np.arange(0.25, 10.01, 0.025).tolist(),
    #'gamma':  np.arange(0, 5.01, 0.25).tolist(),
    #'reg_lambda': [0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1.0, 5.0, 10.0, 50.0, 100.0],
    #'scale_pos_weight' :  [1, 10, 25, 50, 75, 99, 100, 1000] ,
    'verbosity': [0]


}

xgb_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=xgb,
                               param_distributions=xgb_hyperparameters,
                               n_iter=  150, cv=  kf, verbose=1,
                               random_state=42, n_jobs=-1, #scoring = 'precision'
                               )
xgb_random.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

when the next row is running:

```
xgb_random.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
  File "sklearn\utils\_random.pyx", line 223, in sklearn.utils._random.sample_without_replacement
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

The strange thing is that if I  delete the line:

```
min_child_weight':  np.arange(0.25, 10.01, 0.025).tolist(),
```

and the code is:

```
  xgb_hyperparameters = {
    # 'n_estimators': np.arange(2000, 5001, 1000).tolist(),
    'n_estimators': [100],
    'max_depth':  np.arange(3, 16, 1).tolist() ,
    'learning_rate': learning_rate ,
    'min_child_weight':  np.arange(0, 8.01, 0.1).tolist(),
    'subsample':  np.arange(0.25, 1.01, 0.025).tolist(),
    'colsample_bytree': np.arange(0.3, 1.01, 0.025).tolist(),
    'colsample_bylevel': np.arange(0.3, 1.01, 0.025).tolist(),
    #'gamma':  np.arange(0, 5.01, 0.25).tolist(),
    #'reg_lambda': [0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1.0, 5.0, 10.0, 50.0, 100.0],
    #'scale_pos_weight' :  [1, 10, 25, 50, 75, 99, 100, 1000] ,
    'verbosity': [0]


}
```

it works. I think it will  also work if I delete other lines instead of  'min_child_weight' line

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. the grid_size was bigger than the max value for int and this part of code (it running when using the fit function) returned the error:

```
    def __iter__(self):
    rng = check_random_state(self.random_state)

    # if all distributions are given as lists, we want to sample without
    # replacement
    if self._is_all_lists():
        # look up sampled parameter settings in parameter grid
        param_grid = ParameterGrid(self.param_distributions)
        grid_size = len(param_grid)
        n_iter = self.n_iter
```

I reduced the hyperparameters values range and it works